# Input points shapefile in shiny app

Tags: shapefile, r, point, shiny

The application I created allows me to import a polygon shapefile into my Leaflet map. However, I would like to set up a point shapefile import on the same button. I tried several attempts, especially with "addCircles". One or the other works, but not both at the same time. How could I go about it? Here is my code:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(
      dashboardPage(

    #bandeau principal
    dashboardHeader(title ="Sen2extract"),

    #menu a gauche
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
          #Les differents widgets du menu
        menuItem("Carte", tabName= "carte", icon = icon("globe")),
          fileInput(inputId = "shp", label = "Importer un shape :", multiple = TRUE, accept = c('.shp', '.dbf','.sbn', '.sbx', '.shx', '.prj')),
          actionButton(inputId ="reset", label = "", icon = icon("trash-alt")),
          selectInput(inputId ="dataset", label ="Choisir un indice :", choices = c("NDVI", "NDWI GAO", "NDWI MCF", "MNDWI")),
          br(),
          dateRangeInput(inputId ="dates", label = "Selectionner les dates :", start = "2019-01-01"),
          submitButton("Rechercher", icon("cog", lib = "glyphicon")),
          downloadButton("downloadData", label = "Exporter en CSV"),
          br(),br(),
        menuItem("A propos", tabName = "about", icon = icon("list-alt")),
        menuItem("FAQ", tabName = "faq", icon = icon("question-sign",lib= "glyphicon"))
      )
    ),

    #contenu de l'application
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName ="carte",leafletOutput(outputId = "map", width="100%",height = "1100")),
        tabItem(tabName ="about",h1("Bienvenue sur l'application sen2extract !"),
                p("Cet outils permet l'extraction de series temporelles des indices spectraux sur differents sites d'etudes.")),
        tabItem(tabName ="faq", h1("F.A.Q"), h3("Mon shape ne s'importe pas, comment faire ?"),
                p("Referez-vous aux indications de l'onglet Description"),
                h3("L'extraction de ma serie temporelle est anormalement longue, est-ce normal ?"),
                p("Il est possible que l'extraction prenne du temps. Cela va dependre du nombre de polygones en entree, ainsi que de la plage temporelle configuree"))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(utf8)
library(sf)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){


  # create reactive upload file function to store data
  uploadShpfile <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$shp)) {
      shpDF <- input$shp
      pwd <- getwd()
      updir <- dirname(shpDF$datapath[1])
      setwd(updir)
      for (i in 1:nrow(shpDF)) {
        file.rename(shpDF$datapath[i], shpDF$name[i])
      }
      shpName <- shpDF$name[grep(x = shpDF$name, pattern = "*.shp")]
      shpPath <- paste(updir, shpName, sep = "/")
      setwd(pwd)
      shpFile <- readOGR(shpPath)
      shpFile <- spTransform(shpFile,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
    }
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri World Imagery", options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 17)) %>%
      addTiles(group = "OSM", options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 17)) %>%
      addMiniMap(toggleDisplay = T) %>%
      setView(lng = 97.963,lat = 20.380, zoom = 6 ) %>%
      addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Esri World Imagery", "OSM"))
  })

  observeEvent(input$shp, {
    if (!is.null(uploadShpfile())) {
      cent <- gCentroid(spgeom = uploadShpfile(), byid = FALSE)
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        addCircleMarkers(data = uploadShpfile()) 
        addPolygons(data = uploadShpfile()) %>%
        setView(lat = slot(cent, "coords")[[2]], lng = slot(cent, "coords")[[1]], zoom = 7)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: The server.R you posted is never going to work not least because there's no pipe between the `addCircleMarkers` and `addPolygons` lines.

Comment: With a pipe, i have this error message : `Warning: Error in polygonData.default: Don't know how to get path data from object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame.`                                               I tried to import your code below, but it doesn't work too. I'm a R rookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the geometry type of your uploaded shapefile and then use a different `add` method depending on it.

You are reading in `sp` class spatial objects with `readOGR`, so use `inherits` with the spatial class to see if it is polygons, lines, points or something else.

Here's a non-tested outline

```
 data = uploadShpfile()
 map = leafletProxy("map")
 if(inherits(data, "SpatialPoints")){
   map = map %>% addCircleMarkers(data)
 }
 if(inherits(data, "SpatialPolygons")){
   map = map %>% addPolygons(data)
 }

 map = map  %>%
        setView(lat = slot(cent, "coords")[[2]], lng = slot(cent, "coords")[[1]], zoom = 7)
 map
```

Now I'm not sure if that works inside a shiny `observeEvent` expression (because I'm never sure when things get evaluated here) but that shows the logic - test the object's geometry type, do one thing *or* the other in your leaflet map construction, breaking it down into parts rather than sticking it into one pipe expression.

This code would probably be clearer without **any** pipe expressions at this point.

Comment: With a observeEvent, i received this error message when i try to upload a shapefile : Warning: Error in derivePolygons: addPolygons must be called with both lng and lat, or with neither.